# como puedo escoger un elemento especifico de un array con .map en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Estoy creando una base de datos de una tienda usando `mongoDB`, tengo un documento asi:

[image: datos de mongo]

y estoy usando el `.map` de esta manera:

```
{Elemento.ElementosTienda.map(p=> {
//aqui realizo el punto map
                       return <tr key={nanoid()} value={p._id}>
                           <th>{p.Nombre}</th>
                           <th>{p.Serial}</th>
                           <th>{p.Estado}</th>
                           <th>{p.Referencia}</th>
                           </tr>; 
                           })}
```

El problema es que necesito sacar un objeto en específico, por ejemplo, el primero que lleva un teclado y si lo trato de sacar con la variable `p` solo se me queda guardado el ultimo de la lista
¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: A qué te refieres cuando dices que quieres sacar un objeto en específico? Quieres que el `map` devuelva todos menos ese?

Comment: Si necesitas uno en particular usa filter en vez de map

Comment: @HernánGarcia Yo no diría "_en vez_" diría más en combinación con `map`. La idea sería usar un `filter` para quedarse con el producto que le interesa y mostrar ese producto con el `map` justo como ya lo tiene. Sólo con `filter` en react no puedes mostrar `JSX`. Otra alternativa es dentro del `map` preguntar con un `if` por el producto que te interesa. Si es el producto que te interesa devuelves el `JSX`, de lo contrario retornas `null`.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes intentar con el find, que te devuelve el primer elemento que coincida con tu condición, de lo contrario devuelve undefined.

```
let obj = Elemento.ElementosTienda.find(p => p.id === 5);
```

obj será el primer objeto que encuentre en el array que cumpla con la condición, independientemente de que haya otros iguales, devuelve undefined cuando no encuentra nada.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar un filter

```
const array = Elemento.ElementosTienda.filter( p=> p.id === (id que buscas))
```

En el array deberás tener todos los objetos que cumplen la condición y puedes usarlo como quieras...
Mas info del  [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)